# Remove seconds from date Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column with a date (StartTime) in the following format: **28-7-2015  0:09:00** the same dataframe contains also a column that contains the number of seconds (SetupDuration1).

I would like to create a new column that subtracts the number of seconds from the datefield,

```
dftask['Start'] = dftask['StartTime'] - dftask['SetupDuration1']
```

The SetupDuration1 column is a numeric column and must stay a numeric column because I do different operations on this column, take absolute value etc.

So how should I subtract the number of seconds in the correct way. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` a lambda to convert to timedelta and then subtract:

```
In [88]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'StartTime':pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end = dt.datetime(2015,2,1)), 'SetupDuration1':np.random.randint(0, 59, size=32)})
df

Out[88]:
    SetupDuration1  StartTime
0               14 2015-01-01
1               55 2015-01-02
2               21 2015-01-03
3               50 2015-01-04
4               21 2015-01-05
5                6 2015-01-06
6                6 2015-01-07
7                2 2015-01-08
8               10 2015-01-09
9                3 2015-01-10
10              11 2015-01-11
11              32 2015-01-12
12              53 2015-01-13
13              45 2015-01-14
14              48 2015-01-15
15              23 2015-01-16
16               7 2015-01-17
17               5 2015-01-18
18              18 2015-01-19
19              26 2015-01-20
20              48 2015-01-21
21               8 2015-01-22
22              58 2015-01-23
23              24 2015-01-24
24              47 2015-01-25
25              10 2015-01-26
26              32 2015-01-27
27              26 2015-01-28
28              36 2015-01-29
29              36 2015-01-30
30              40 2015-01-31
31              18 2015-02-01

In [94]:
df['Start'] = df['StartTime'] - df['SetupDuration1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, 's'))
df

Out[94]:
    SetupDuration1  StartTime               Start
0               14 2015-01-01 2014-12-31 23:59:46
1               55 2015-01-02 2015-01-01 23:59:05
2               21 2015-01-03 2015-01-02 23:59:39
3               50 2015-01-04 2015-01-03 23:59:10
4               21 2015-01-05 2015-01-04 23:59:39
5                6 2015-01-06 2015-01-05 23:59:54
6                6 2015-01-07 2015-01-06 23:59:54
7                2 2015-01-08 2015-01-07 23:59:58
8               10 2015-01-09 2015-01-08 23:59:50
9                3 2015-01-10 2015-01-09 23:59:57
10              11 2015-01-11 2015-01-10 23:59:49
11              32 2015-01-12 2015-01-11 23:59:28
12              53 2015-01-13 2015-01-12 23:59:07
13              45 2015-01-14 2015-01-13 23:59:15
14              48 2015-01-15 2015-01-14 23:59:12
15              23 2015-01-16 2015-01-15 23:59:37
16               7 2015-01-17 2015-01-16 23:59:53
17               5 2015-01-18 2015-01-17 23:59:55
18              18 2015-01-19 2015-01-18 23:59:42
19              26 2015-01-20 2015-01-19 23:59:34
20              48 2015-01-21 2015-01-20 23:59:12
21               8 2015-01-22 2015-01-21 23:59:52
22              58 2015-01-23 2015-01-22 23:59:02
23              24 2015-01-24 2015-01-23 23:59:36
24              47 2015-01-25 2015-01-24 23:59:13
25              10 2015-01-26 2015-01-25 23:59:50
26              32 2015-01-27 2015-01-26 23:59:28
27              26 2015-01-28 2015-01-27 23:59:34
28              36 2015-01-29 2015-01-28 23:59:24
29              36 2015-01-30 2015-01-29 23:59:24
30              40 2015-01-31 2015-01-30 23:59:20
31              18 2015-02-01 2015-01-31 23:59:42
```

**Timings**

Actually it looks quicker to just construct a Timedeltaindex inplace:

```
In [99]:
%timeit df['Start'] = df['StartTime'] - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['SetupDuration1'], unit='s')
1000 loops, best of 3: 837 µs per loop

In [100]:
%timeit df['Start'] = df['StartTime'] - df['SetupDuration1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, 's'))
100 loops, best of 3: 1.97 ms per loop
```

So I'd just do:

```
In [101]:
df['Start'] = df['StartTime'] - pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['SetupDuration1'], unit='s')
df

Out[101]:
    SetupDuration1  StartTime               Start
0               14 2015-01-01 2014-12-31 23:59:46
1               55 2015-01-02 2015-01-01 23:59:05
2               21 2015-01-03 2015-01-02 23:59:39
3               50 2015-01-04 2015-01-03 23:59:10
4               21 2015-01-05 2015-01-04 23:59:39
5                6 2015-01-06 2015-01-05 23:59:54
6                6 2015-01-07 2015-01-06 23:59:54
7                2 2015-01-08 2015-01-07 23:59:58
8               10 2015-01-09 2015-01-08 23:59:50
9                3 2015-01-10 2015-01-09 23:59:57
10              11 2015-01-11 2015-01-10 23:59:49
11              32 2015-01-12 2015-01-11 23:59:28
12              53 2015-01-13 2015-01-12 23:59:07
13              45 2015-01-14 2015-01-13 23:59:15
14              48 2015-01-15 2015-01-14 23:59:12
15              23 2015-01-16 2015-01-15 23:59:37
16               7 2015-01-17 2015-01-16 23:59:53
17               5 2015-01-18 2015-01-17 23:59:55
18              18 2015-01-19 2015-01-18 23:59:42
19              26 2015-01-20 2015-01-19 23:59:34
20              48 2015-01-21 2015-01-20 23:59:12
21               8 2015-01-22 2015-01-21 23:59:52
22              58 2015-01-23 2015-01-22 23:59:02
23              24 2015-01-24 2015-01-23 23:59:36
24              47 2015-01-25 2015-01-24 23:59:13
25              10 2015-01-26 2015-01-25 23:59:50
26              32 2015-01-27 2015-01-26 23:59:28
27              26 2015-01-28 2015-01-27 23:59:34
28              36 2015-01-29 2015-01-28 23:59:24
29              36 2015-01-30 2015-01-29 23:59:24
30              40 2015-01-31 2015-01-30 23:59:20
31              18 2015-02-01 2015-01-31 23:59:42
```